# Probability to pick an integer number $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ from the field $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: probability-theory

In the field of the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$, we build a subset $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ $A=\{k\}, k\in\mathbb{Z}, k=-N,-N+1,...,0,1,2,..,N$. If we pick infinite times a number $x$ from $\mathbb{R}$ with normal probability $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma), \sigma\gt0$, the probability $p$ to have $x\in A$, is still $p=0$ even in the case $N\to\infty$? Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by $N\to \infty$ ? You mean $A = \mathbb{Z}$? In this case - of course. Is A given as $A=\{-N,\dots,N\}$ ?

Comment: @Adam: Yes. Exactly.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ is a set of measure zero so the probability should be zero.

Comment: You probably mean $-N+1$

Comment: @DanZimm. Right. I corrected the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a sequence of random variables with nondegenerate normal distributions, then $P(X_n\in\mathbb Z)=0$ for every $n$, hence
$$
P(\exists n\in\mathbb N,\,X_n\in\mathbb Z)\leqslant\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(X_n\in\mathbb Z)=0,
$$
that is, $$
P(\exists n\in\mathbb N,\,X_n\in\mathbb Z)=0.
$$
This does not assume independence, only that the distribution of each $X_n$ is absolutely continuous (and that the set $\mathbb N$ is countable, of course).